# is possible to apply an aggregate function on a alias in a list of select statement?

Tags: postgresql

I wrote a query as below, and the result shows: ERROR: syntax error at or near "rank"
Position: 58.
I don't know why it is wrong and I guess that is because aggregate not allowed to work on alias"hours". Can someone help me clarify this question? I appreciate it.

```
SELECT
    firstname,
    surname,
    (sum(bks.slots * 0.5)) AS hours rank(hours) DESC AS rank
FROM
    cd.members mem
    INNER JOIN cd.bookings bks ON mem.memid = bks.memid
GROUP BY
    firstname,
    surname
ORDER BY
    hours DESC;
```

Comment: `rank` is not an aggregate function, it's a window function. `RANK() OVER ([PARTITION BY partition_expression, ... ] ORDER BY sort_expression [ASC | DESC], ...)`. It accepts no parameter and after the keyword `rank()` should follow `over(...`, that's why it complains `error near rank`

Comment: Thank you. what if I write like this: "rank ( ) over (order by hours desc) as rank ", cause I have already defined hours as (sum(bks.slots*0.5)), previously?

Answer (score 0):

I guess first you want to calculate the `hours` and then rank it. If so, then select statement should be something like that:

```
SELECT
    firstname,
    surname,
    hours,
    rank() OVER (ORDER BY hours DESC) AS ranking
FROM (
    SELECT
        firstname,
        surname,
        (sum(bks.slots * 0.5)) AS hours
    FROM
        cd.members mem
        INNER JOIN cd.bookings bks ON mem.memid = bks.memid
    GROUP BY
        firstname,
        surname) AS tab1
ORDER BY
    ranking DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I do, but why it is impossible by doing my way: aliasing expression as hours, and then ranking hours, both in select statement?